# android how to give click event on gallery item

Tags: android

http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html

Just go through the above link. there is an example sample code for Android Coverflow widget.
I want to give click event on the images. How can I do it.
Plz suggest me any way.
Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Follow below code

```
mCoverFlow.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long arg3)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

Comment: How to get that particular image on which i clicked?

Comment: if I need to auto excute setOnItemClickListener just like setClickable with onClickListener.. then what should be done ... thank's for your concern..

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, since the widget extends from `Gallery`, presumably you can just add an onItemClickListener:

```
coverFlowView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> gallery, View view, int position, long id) {
    //do stuff!
  }
});
```

in the same way, you can set an onItemSelectedListener, which fires whenever an item is "selected" (comes in the center of the gallery:

```
    coverFlowView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
      @Override
      public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> list, View view, int position, long id) {
        //do stuff!
      }

      @Override
      public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
      }
    });
```

Comment: How to get that particular image on which i clicked?

Comment: Use the position int that is passed as an argument into the method.